# Logic and query for getting first name from full name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large database with a full name field. The full name can be in any format and can also include title. For example, all of the following are possible:

```
John Smith
Smith, John
Mr. John Smith
Dr. John Smith
Mrs. Jane Smith
Ms. Jane Smith
Jane Smith, Esq.
Jane Smith, MD
```

I want to preserve the full name field, but also add a predicted first name field from a separate table (that contains name, gender).

I think the proper logic for this is to match the first name values + a space to the full name table via LIKE. The space is so that "David Johnson" doesn't match to "John."

I think the way to accomplish this is an update statement with a subquery in it. Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE "employees" 
    SET "employees".FirstName = (SELECT  firstname 
                                 FROM genders 
                                 WHERE fullname LIKE '%"employees".FirstName %')
```

Comment: `LIKE '%"return_skdjrltdorgoffcrtrstkyempl".FirstName %'` -- can you clarify what that's supposed to be? Because it makes no sense. You saying the `fullname` value will contain the literal text `"return_skdjrltdorgoffcrtrstkyempl".FirstName `?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea, IMO you should calculate fields like this in code and not store the result. It seems unlikely that a good enough sql statement could be created to do this properly.

Comment: Sorry I've edited the table name to be "employees" I thought that the actual name caused too much confusion. I'm trying to check if the value in the employees table (i.e. John Smith) contains a value in the genders.firstname column.

Comment: In any case `fullname LIKE '%"employees".FirstName %'` isn't checking the `fullname` value against the value of the `FirstName` field in the `employees` table, it's comparing it against the literal string `"employees".FirstName `. You'd need to do something like `WHERE fullname LIKE '%' || "employees".FirstName || ' %'` to do that comparison.

Comment: When dealing with names, be sure to read [this](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want to do is use Postgres's full text search capabilities. You can create a stopwords list containing titles to exclude (Mr, Ms, etc.). Then, set up a search configuration to use your stopwords.

Once you've set up your search configuration correctly, your query will look something like this (this is the `SELECT` variant: Changing to `UPDATE` will be trivial):

```
SELECT employees.full_name, genders.first_name 
FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN genders ON
        TO_TSVECTOR('english_titles', employees.full_name) 
            @@ TO_TSQUERY('english_titles', genders.first_name)
```

This will give you the following results:

```
full_name           first_name          
"John Smith"        "John"
"Smith, John"       "John"
"Mr. John Smith"    "John"
"Dr. John Smith"    "John"
"Mrs. Jane Smith"   "Jane"
"Ms. Jane Smith"    "Jane"
"Jane Smith, Esq."  "Jane"
"Jane Smith, MD"    "Jane"
"David Johnson"     NULL
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to take the following steps:

1. Create a stopwords file containing job titles, and put it in your `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data` Postgres directory. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS.
2. Create a dictionary that uses this stopwords list (you can probably use the `pg_catalog.simple` as your template dictionary). See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY.
3. Create a search configuration for job titles. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-configuration.html.
4. Alter your search configuration to use the dictionary you created in Step 2 (cf. the link above).

Now, with all that said, you need to think carefully about a couple of things:

- How do you expect to handle people whose last name matches a first name in your `Genders` table? For example, you have someone called `John Stuart`, and both `John` and `Stuart` are in your `genders` table. How do you expect to handle that?
- How do you expect to handle people with nicknames, or only have one name? I would **strongly** encourage you to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) to make sure you're not making any ill-founded assumptions.
- Why is your table containing first named called `genders`? Do you expect to match people to first-name by gender? If so, that's a dangerous road to go down---there are names that can be used for either sex.